# Как посчитать число значений в cgridview с учетом фильтра?

Tags: yii

Как правильно сделать подсчет значений в колонке `cgridview`, если в зависимости от фильтра количество ячеек в колонке меняется.

Comment: неужели никто не может помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataProvider, используемый для построения CGrivView, имеет свойство totalItemCount, которое содержит количество столбцов